# Google App Engine Launcher - CGI / FastCGI has stopped working

Tags: google-app-engine, google-app-engine-launch

Using the Google Identity Toolkit SDK for Php with Google App Engine Launcher causes this error to appear. 'CGI / FastCGI has stopped working'.

As soon as you implement:

```
Gitkit_Client::createFromFile('/gitkit-server-config.json');
```

The crash will occur.

This is using the 1.9.30 version of Google App Engine Launcher that was recently released.

Comment: I have the problem where anytime i use git or save updates it will about half of the time crash between 1-5 times. Some say that in the app.yaml file, runtime: php55 is the cause. I would try it, but i kind of need that php version.

Comment: I still have seemingly random crashes, I believe to be based on a number of back to back requests which sounds like what you describe, but I did find a solution to the specific problem I mentioned above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't already have one, create a php.ini in the root of your project and add this line to enable the full version of curl.

```
extension = "php_curl.dll"
```

This solution has worked to resolve the error for me.

Comment: I do not know if it is coincidence or not, but it does seem at a glance that the number of times CGI crashes has gone down. Will continue trying it out though. Also, isn't it php.ini not inin

Comment: Fixed the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. There's also an [open issue](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=12287). Waiting for a fix, I "solved" downgrading the Google App Engine SDK for PHP to version 1.9.23. Tried also every version from 1.9.24 to 1.9.31, but none seems to work.